# Fixed background not stretching to full window

Tags: html, css, image, background

I have a fixed background on my site that is supposed to stretch depending on the browser window size. For some reason, however, there is a small strip of white at the bottom before reaching the footer.

Perhaps there is some issue with how I am going about this in the CSS?

Here is my html:

```
<div class="clear" id='content'>    
    <br> 
    <br>
    <br>
        <?php 
            $section = $_GET["section"];
            if ($section == 'changePassword'){
                include "changePassword.php";
            }elseif ($section == "contactinfo"){
                include "contactInfo.php";
            }elseif ($section == "publicinfo"){
                include "publicInfo.php";
            }elseif ($section == "import"){
                include "import.php";
            }elseif ($section == "users"){
                include "viewUsers.php";
            }elseif ($section == "sales"){
                include "sales.php";
            }elseif ($section == "statements"){
                include "./statements.php";
            }elseif ($section == "books"){
                include "viewBooks.php";
            }elseif ($section == "specialists"){
                include "booking.php";
            }elseif ($section == "viewUser"){
                include "viewUser.php";
            }elseif ($section == "logAsUser"){
                include "loginAsUser.php";
            }else{
                include "account.php";
            }
            //specialists
        ?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.clear {
background: url('../assets/19.jpg') no-repeat fixed ;
background-size:100% 100%;
position: initial;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-repeat: repeat-y;
```

}

Thanks!

Comment: please add a js-fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your div wouldn't stretch equal to browser height to make `background-size` property work. Add this **CSS**:

```
html, body, .clear {
  height:100%;
}
```

You have to specify height with `html` and `body` selectors together. And that `.clear` `div` has to be the direct child of `BODY`. Else the solution wouldn't work. You don't have to specify `width:100%;` as default block elements covers the width.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DGFnT/

Comment: Awesome! This fixed the issue after applying a different <body> tag to the fixed pages versus the scrolling pages. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Your `.clear` css is adding a background-size, but you're not setting a height and width.

Try adding `width:100%` and `height:100%` to your `.clear` css

Comment: When I add these, it changes the space to underneath the footer, rather than above the footer. Is there an easy fix for this as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try  using`background-size: cover` rather than `background-size:100% 100%`.

Comment: Added this in along with the mozilla and webkit implementations. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why but you are assigning no repeat to **.clear** but then telling it to repeat-x and repeat-y... anyway if you wish tho have the background cover the whole viewport ensure that you have **height: 100%** for the **.clear** container and then you can use **background-size: cover** like so:

```
.clear{
    height: 100%;
    background: url('../assets/19.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This definitely helped me clean up my css, although it didn't fix the issue.